# Convert string values starting with a specific letter in a list to integer

Tags: python, jupyter

List Values

```
49           873
50           575
51           487
52    B000XPZCXW
53    B098LPQ5LM
54    B09W5S7GFK
```

All the values starting with 'B' need to converted into 1

Output

```
49           873
50           575
51           487
52             1
53             1
54             1
```

I was hoping to use 'startswith' lambda function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you want.

```py
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
lst = [
    (49, "873"),
    (50, "575"),
    (51, "487"),
    (52, "B000XPZCXW"),
    (53, "B098LPQ5LM"),
    (54, "B09W5S7GFK")
]
f = lambda x: 1 if x.startswith("B") else x
for i in lst:
    print((i[0], f(i[1])))
# Output
# (49, '873')
# (50, '575')
# (51, '487')
# (52, 1)
# (53, 1)
# (54, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of lambda function we can use list

`old_list  = ["873" ,"575" , "487" , "B000XPZCXW" , "B098LPQ5LM" , "B09W5S7GFK" ]`

`new_list =  [ "1"  if x[0]=="B" else x for x in old_list ]`